# Compiling application using Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, sencha-touch, facebook-javascript-sdk, sencha-touch-2

I stumbled upon an issue when trying to compile my application which is using **Facebook Javascript SDK** :

```
[ERROR] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FB
```

This is my setup :

**index.html**

```
...


<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>

  <!-- dependencies -->
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//payme.com:3000/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>
...
```

**Home.js** (where the error is caught)

```
...
  config: {
    controls: {
      mainView: {
        initialize: 'initView'
      }
    }
  },

  initView: function() {
    var me = this;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if(response.status === 'connected') {       
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    });
  },
...
```

I tried to load Facebook SDK asynchronously and synchronously, place the script tag after and before the microloader but nothing works.

**Any idea on how to fix this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the Facebook JavaScript SDK asynchronously and probably calling the method `FB.getLoginStatus` before the SDK is loaded. Call the method `FB.getLoginStatus` after the SDK is loaded (i.e. on the line where you have `// Additional initialization code here` )